# Why can't I store URIs in ApplicationData

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-store-apps

According to [`ApplicationData.LocalSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings) I should be able to store a `Uri` in Local Settings but the following code is throwing: `Data of this type is not supported.`

```
ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
localSettings["newURI"] = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
```

This looks like a bug on their end but I wanted to see if anyone had a similar issue first.

Answer (score 1):

It is a documentation bug, sorry.  Store it as a string, instead.

Comment: How do you know this is a documentation bug?